# Move files from a date and time stamped directory

Tags: ruby

I am pulling down files from a private GitHub repo and it's being put in a temporary folder that is date and time stamped so it changes every time. Is there a way I can capture that as a variable and move the files from that folder in to another folder?

I have tried the following where the ** is a glob for the folder `"/app/temp/20160202121441/"` that the name changes on each download;

```
 Dir.chdir("/app/temp")
 tempfiles = File.join("**", "*")
 tempfiles.each do |file|
   dest_folder = "/app/files/"
   FileUtils.cp(file, dest_folder)
 end
```

Comment: Also noticed that I can't call `.each` on `tempfiles` so I need help with that too!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the files in that folder and move them with Fileutils.mv

```
dest_folder = "/app/files/"
Dir.glob("/app/tmp/*".each do |file|
  Fileutils.mv(file, dest_folder)
end
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think my description was very good. I want to completely remove the files from the date-stamped folder so they would come out of `"/app/temp/20160202121441/"` and go into `"/app/files/"`

Comment: Oh, so just use FileUtils.mv instead of FileUtils.cp if you want to move files. I'll edit my answer.